# Using for-while or some other sequence functions

Tags: function, clojure, sequence

```
user> (for [n '(9) d '(2 3 5 7) :while (not= 0 (mod n d))] n)
```

It gives me,

```
user> (9)
```

And if I change the sequence in the list like this,

```
user> (for [n '(9) d '(2 5 3 7) :while (not= 0 (mod n d))] n)
```

Then it gives me,

```
user> (9 9)
```

Actually, I'm trying to get an empty list, if the integer `n` is divisible by any integer of sequence `d`; otherwise `n`. So, the question is, is there any `seq` function, or a combination of few, that can do the trick? Or do I have to use `loop-recurr`, or recursion, thing whatsoever?

Comment: Hi @AdeelAnsari, i think  '(n) is not an integer but a sequence with one integer, Are you right with this notion?

Comment: Yes, here it's a `seq`. Actually, `integer` is not allowed there in the `for` function. Sorry about that. I mean it can be a number if some function is fine with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the function you are looking for is [`filter`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/filter).

> Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which (pred item)
>   returns true. pred must be free of side-effects.

The following function, `divisible-by-fn`, returns the number in the `seq` that is divisible by `n`

```
(defn divisible-by-fn [your-integer your-seq]
  (filter #(zero? (mod your-integer %))your-seq))
(divisible-by-fn 9 '(2 5 3 7))
=>(3)
```

... but, in case, you need to get an empty list, if the integer `n` is divisible by any integer, `d`, in the `seq`; otherwise n, then

```
(defn your-fn [your-integer your-seq]
(if-not (not-any? #(zero? (mod your-integer %))your-seq)
 ()
 your-integer)
)
(your-fn 9 '(2 5 3 7))
=> () 
(your-fn 11 '(2 5 3 7))
=> 11
```

Comment: I love this. Wait a while, let me try.

Comment: I suppose, I can't use this, `(filter #(zero? (mod your-integer %))your-seq)` as an argument to `recur`; because its a lazy sequence. Am I correct?

Comment: I've used the (next ..) function as argument on recur function, so it's clear that you can use lazy sequences inside recur or loop functions, no problem with this!